# javascript mocha framework with selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js

[enter image description here][1][I m new to java script and mocha framework. I cant pass this error. in my application,browser goes to next page where i need to click and enter customer info(name,lastname,city)etc but I am getting this error. but as soon as I go to the next page,page kinda gets blurry ,it looks like it s refreshing but doesnt click on the box to enter info;

I have used this code to handle the error but it waits like 10 seconds and enters the info but this time I get this error an test case fails.
I would really appreciate your help

```
 Uncaught ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.193)][2]


 1- await driver.findElement(By.id("billing_email")).sendKeys("Tester@test.com")

    
    2- var element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ccnumber']"))
    -3 driver.executeAsyncScript("arguments[0].click();",element);

   -4 await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ccnumber']")).click()
    5-await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ccnumber']")).sendKeys("**** **** **** ****")
```

it gives me the session timeout error before clicking on the element

Comment: Please, can you post your test code and edit the question with text instead of photos?

Comment: did you see the code @J.F.?